# Parsing error in index.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-hot-loader, npm-start

I am trying to use react hot loader. I am getting an error while I run "npm start" command in terminal. Can some please tell me what is the problem. I am struggling for having react hot loader working but not getting launched anything in browser.

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import allReducers from './reducers'
import App from './Components/App'
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

const store = createStore(allReducers);
injectTapEventPlugin();
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image: Terminal error]

webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000
    },

    devtool: 'eval',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './dev/js/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

    ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-redux-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.8",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get an error like this it is due to not being able to transpile the jsx. in your case i believe it is because you are not using the babel-loader to accomplish it. Additionally if you want to use presents you need to include them as a query parameter to the babel-loader. I also like to exclude the node-modules to reduce the time for transpilation.

```
{
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
     presets:['es2015','react','stage-0'] // Babel presets, I use stage-0 
  },
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
}
```